# Precondition Error while invoking restTemplate exchange or execute

Tags: rest, netflix-eureka, spring-restcontroller, netflix-zuul, spring-rest

I am trying to invoke a call to a rest service. Both the rest client and rest service are running in my machine in different ports. Both execute and exchange method is throwing the null pointer exception. My rest client is a Netflix Zuul Filter (which is registered itself with Netflix Eureka Discovery agent). I hope that doesn't makes a difference but, ***the end of stack trace seems to mention about 'ribbon' libraries. So i guess the error might be something related to it.***

I have just `@Autowired` the RestTemplate object in my Rest Client. I have not used the `@LoadBalanced` Annotation.

When i use a 'Eureka Service' ID instead of localhost:port number, the call gets executed successfully. What could be the root case ?

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8085/helloWorld, HttpMethod.GET, entity, HttpServletResponse.class);
```

Exception Stack track:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3936) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
       at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerStats.getServerStats(LoadBalancerStats.java:167) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.0-RC13.jar:na]
       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerStats.getSingleServerStat(LoadBalancerStats.java:354) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.0-RC13.jar:na]
       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerStats(LoadBalancerContext.java:621) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.0-RC13.jar:na]
       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:71) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:84) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:568) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:447) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had missed to inject the restTemplate in my configuration class. Once i added the following code snippet to my configuration class, it worked fine. The rest call got invoked.

```
 @Bean
   RestTemplate restTemplate() {
       return new RestTemplate();
   }
```

Not sure how the rest call worked fine before, while using Eureka service ID instead of an URL.